# Windows 10 - Error dialog on start up

Tags: windows, windows-10

Today I found that after I logged in to my laptop, a dialog as below appeared.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt6NA.png]

I am running a Chinese version of Windows 10, the title of that dialog reads "Error", and there is a "OK" button. I tracked it down from the task manager, and it points to `c:\Windows\syswow64\dllhost.exe`

What is the cause of this problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Don't click the error message away. Run [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), use the crosshair from  its toolbar

[image: Process Explorer CrossHair]

and move it to the Error message. This will highlight the program which causes the error message. Now you see which program causes it and you can uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

(+1) for magicandre1981's answer. It should help you find the offending program.

As you said this message is occurring at logon, you may consider running MalwareBytes Junkware Removal Tool which removes startup entries and scheduled tasks and other PUP/malware-laden files or registry entries.

If the problem occurs again, run [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), enable the Hide Microsoft Entries checkbox, and inspect every 3rd party item listed in the Everything tab. If you need more assistance, save the log, upload and provide use the link.